# What does it mean CTP and PPR?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I starting figure out in `apache.poi` and I couldn't understand what does it mean CTP and PPr in `XWPFParagraph`. I have following code:

```
targetParagraph.getCTP()
               .setPPr(index.getParagraph().getCTP().getPPr());
```

I not found describing of this methods in official documentation `apache.poi`
Can you explain to me what is it or get me some link where I can read about it?

Thanks for help!

Comment: You generally don't want to be using those low-level classes unless you really know what you're doing....

Comment: @Gagravarr Sadly there are many cases when you have to use those low-level classes, especially when working with word documents.

Answer (score 2):

`getCTP()` returns org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTP which from my understanding represends a paragraph on a lower level, strictly related to the xml. It is annotated as `@Internal` - it can be changed without much notice.

More of a guess but I'd say that `getPPr()` returns an object that represents a paragraph properties.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is not any documentation about the ooxml schemas, the low level basic objects of `apache poi`, public available. So we need downloading the sources of [ooxml-schemas](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/poi/ooxml-schemas/1.4/) and then doing `javadoc` form those to get a API documentation which describes the classes and methods.

There we then find `org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTP`, which is a paragraph in a `Office Open XML` word processing document and `org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTPPr`, which are paragraph properties in that kind of document.

Note `ooxml-schemas` version `1.4` is for usage together with `apache poi 4.0.0` or newer. For older versions  `ooxml-schemas` version `1.3` is needed.

Comment: @Axei Richter Thanks for help!