# CTR Class Documentation

Tags: java, xml, apache-poi

I want to set a style of a XWPFRun object to another XWPFRun object. I got a instance of org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTR class by using .getCTR() method. But I couldn't find any documentation about class CTR and package. Is there document on the web?

Comment: It's auto-generated from the OOXML schemas. They're public, but not the easiest to understand as a beginner...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57407697/what-does-it-mean-ctp-and-ppr/57408443#57408443